# How to use regular expression using python

Tags: python, regex, string, extract, python-re

I have the following string:

```
data='POLYGON ((1280 16068, 1294 16059, 1297 16060, 1300 16063, 1303 16065, 1308 16066, 1311 16068, 1314 16071, 1316 16074, 1316 16078, 1313 16081))'
```

I would like to extract only the numbers in the parenthesis (with one parenthesis, not two). How do I write an optimal regular expression for that?

What I tried so far?

```
print(data.extract('.........(.*)'))
```

This does extract only the numbers, but I am not sure how to replace the (.)s.

Required Output:

```
(1280 16068, 1294 16059, 1297 16060, 1300 16063, 1303 16065, 1308 16066, 1311 16068, 1314 16071, 1316 16074, 1316 16078, 1313 16081)
```

Comment: The data you provided does not look like a string.

Comment: That doesn't look like a string at all. Do you mean you have a string which contains `"data=POLYGON ((1280 16068, 1294 16059, 1297 16060, 1300 16063, 1303 16065, 1308 16066, 1311 16068, 1314 16071, 1316 16074, 1316 16078, 1313 16081))"`? And what's `data.extract`?

Comment: `re.search(r'(\([^()]+\))', strn)` would trivially match the partenthesized list of numbers, but it probably not precise enough if you can have other input which contains parentheses which should not be extracted.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure regex isn't necessary here.

Let's say your string is : `string = "data=POLYGON ((1280 16068, 1294 16059, 1297 16060, 1300 16063, 1303 16065, 1308 16066, 1311 16068, 1314 16071, 1316 16074, 1316 16078, 1313 16081))"`

In this case, the easier way would be to do :

```
res = "("+string.split("(")[2][:-1]
```

output :

```
(1280 16068, 1294 16059, 1297 16060, 1300 16063, 1303 16065, 1308 16066, 1311 16068, 1314 16071, 1316 16074, 1316 16078, 1313 16081)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use regex use package "re"

```
 import re

  data='POLYGON ((1280 16068, 1294 16059, 1297 16060, 1300 16063, 1303 16065, 1308 16066, 1311 16068, 1314 16071, 1316 16074, 1316 16078, 1313 16081))'
  x = re.search("your regex here", txt)
```